# Rest API Post Decoding Problem while parsing JSON

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use rest API that sends a message to users and get a verification code to verify the user in swift 
but every time I tried on the emulator I have an error and the console prints the error message "decoding Problem"
But the sending method(post) is working so I can receive a message.
I just can't know if my info works on server

Please tell me why decoding Problem has occurred and how can I fix it

There are three code files.
First One is a Model that Requests an API
Second One is a Message Info that I want to post to the server
and the Last One is a Controller that checking if API runs Properly

```swift
import Foundation

enum APIError: Error{
    case responseProblem
    case decodingProblem
    case encodingProblem
}

struct APIRequest {
    let resourceURL: URL

    init(endPoint: String) {
        let resourceString = "https://wageul.heewon.dev/api\(endPoint)"
        guard let resURL = URL(string: resourceString) else{fatalError()}

        self.resourceURL = resURL
    }

    func save(_ messegeToSave: Messege, completion: @escaping(Result<Messege,APIError>) -> Void) {
        do{
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: resourceURL)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
            urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(messegeToSave)

            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data,response, _ in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let jsonData = data else{
                    completion(.failure(.responseProblem))
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let messegeData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Messege.self, from: jsonData)
                    completion(.success(messegeData))
                }catch{
                    completion(.failure(.decodingProblem))
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }catch{
            completion(.failure(.encodingProblem))
        }

    }

}
```

```swift
import Foundation

class Messege: Codable{
    var phone: String
    var code: String?

    init(phone: String) {
        self.phone = phone
        self.code = nil
    }

    init(phone: String, code: String) {
        self.phone = phone
        self.code = code
    }
}
```

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
class PhoneNumCheckController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var codeText: UITextField!

    @IBAction func phoneNumCheckButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let tempPhoneNum = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "tempPhoneNum") as! String

        let messege = Messege(phone: tempPhoneNum, code:codeText.text!)

        let postRequest = APIRequest(endPoint: "/register")
        postRequest.save(messege, completion: { result in
            switch result{
            case .success(let messege):
                print("Messege Sent: \(messege)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error Occured: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }


}
```

Comment: In your `catch` instead of returning `.decodingProblem` return `error` - this is the error that was caught and will tell you what went wrong with the JSONDecoder.

Comment: as @Paulw11 said, change your catch to show the error. Probably, will be something related to mismatch error or a nil value in a non nil variable